PyCharm 2024.1.1 PE Code Completion not working anymore
With the last update of PyCharm, code completion is not working anymore. In Settings/Editor/CodeCompletion I have "Show suggestions as you type" enabled as well as other options. The suggestion to import a missing file is not working anymore as well as  the ctrl-click on a class will not redirect to the class. A missing class is also not red underscored. What am I doing wrong ?
